# Disappearing values in ggvis when using tooltip on grouped data

Tags: r, ggvis

This works fine

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggvis)

years <- as.factor(c(2013,2013,2014,2014,2015,2015))
months <- c(1,2,1,2,1,2)
values <- c(3,2,4,6,5,1)

df <- data.frame(years,months,values)


df %>% 
  group_by(years) %>% 
  ggvis(~months, ~values) %>% 
  layer_points( fill = ~years)
```

However, when I add a tooltip the points all appear momentarily but only the 2015 values remain

```
 df <- cbind(df, id = seq_len(nrow(df))) 

all_values <- function(x) {
  if(is.null(x)) return(NULL)
  row <- df[df$id == x$id,]
  paste0(names(row),": ",format(row), collapse = "<br />")
}

df %>% 
  group_by(years) %>% 
  ggvis(~months, ~values, key:= ~id) %>% 
  layer_points( fill = ~years) %>%
  add_tooltip(all_values, "hover")
```

Probably some simple error, but any help appreciated
cheers

Comment: I don't see what the `group_by` is adding here - you get different groups by using `fill` in `layer_points`.  Your plot appears to work how you want if you remove the `group_by` line.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, trying to add a tooltip specific to a row when the data are grouped doesn't seem to work.  This makes some sense, actually, as the grouping implies that you may want info by group.

You don't need grouping in your `layer_points` example at all, but you would need it if you wanted lines between the points for specific years as well as points.  If this is what you wanted, you'd group the dataset after you add the points, and put `key` in `layer_points` instead of in the overall `ggvis`.

```
df %>% 
    ggvis(~months, ~values) %>% 
    layer_points( fill = ~years, key:= ~id) %>%
    add_tooltip(all_values, "hover") %>%
    group_by(years) %>%
    layer_lines(stroke = ~years, strokeWidth := 2)
```

This isn't totally ideal, because the tooltip still shows up for the lines even though lines don't have unique id data associated with them.  To change this, make a small change to your tooltip function to check just if the id variable is `NULL` rather than the whole dataset from `ggvis`.

```
all_values = function(x) {
    if(is.null(x$id)) return(NULL)
    row <- df[df$id == x$id,]
    paste0(names(row),": ",format(row), collapse = "<br />")
}
```

You can add a tooltip at the group level, but you'll need to figure out what sort of summary info you want to display.  In the function for the tooltip you will be working with the grouping variable instead of `id`.

For example, you could just show all values associated with the group.  The way I've set this up you'll need to click on the line to see the group info:

```
group_values1 = function(x) {
    if(is.null(x)) return(NULL)
    group = df[df$years == unique(x$years),]
    paste0(names(group), ": ", format(group), collapse = "<br />")
}

df %>% 
    ggvis(~months, ~values) %>% 
    layer_points( fill = ~years, key:= ~id) %>%
    add_tooltip(all_values, "hover") %>%
    group_by(years) %>%
    layer_lines(stroke = ~years, strokeWidth := 2) %>%
    add_tooltip(group_values1, "click")
```

You may want to show summary information, instead.  In this example, I'll display the overall change in `values` and how many months passed in the tooltip.  I make the summary dataset with functions from *dplyr*.

```
group_values2 = function(x) {
    if(is.null(x)) return(NULL)
    group = df[df$years == unique(x$years),]
    groupval = group %>% group_by(years) %>% 
        summarise(`Change in value` = max(values) - min(values), 
                            `Months Passed` = max(months) - min(months))
    paste0(names(groupval), ": ", format(groupval), collapse = "<br />")
}

df %>% 
    ggvis(~months, ~values) %>% 
    layer_points( fill = ~years, key:= ~id) %>%
    add_tooltip(all_values, "hover") %>%
    group_by(years) %>%
    layer_lines(stroke = ~years, strokeWidth := 2) %>%
    add_tooltip(group_values2, "click")
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in you putting `group_by` before ggvis and calling `add_tooltip` afterwards. Just put `group_by` part after ggvis call

```
df %>% 
  ggvis(~months, ~values, key:= ~id) %>% 
  group_by(years) %>%
  layer_points( fill = ~years) %>%
  add_tooltip(all_values, "hover")
```

no idea why it happens though

Comment: @RlnatM Tx for suggestion but it makes no difference to the plot when I use your code