# Tooltip in ggvis for R with layer_paths

Tags: r, ggvis, choropleth

I have a trouble about the tooltip function in ggvis for my choropleth plot.I have attached my code below. The code is running good with no tooltip function. But if I add tooltip, only the land of new jersey left(see pic). The other states are missing. Any one can help to have a look and how can I fix it to get the other parts back with tooltip function added? Thanks a lot!
[image: pic]

```
###my data for example
mapdata<-data.frame(
  state=c("alabama","alaska","arizona","arkansas","california","colorado","connecticut","delaware","florida","georgia","hawaii","idaho","illinois","indiana","iowa","kansas","kentucky","louisiana","maine","maryland","massachusetts","michigan", "minnesota","mississippi","missouri","montana","nebraska","nevada","new hampshire","new jersey","new mexico","new york","north carolina","north dakota","ohio","oklahoma", "oregon","pennsylvania","rhode island","south carolina","south dakota","tennessee","texas","utah","vermont","virginia","washington","west virginia","wisconsin","wyoming"),
  revenue=runif(50,min=100,max=9000))

library(rgdal)   
library(ggplot2) 
library(ggvis)

url   <- "http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2014/shp/cb_2014_us_state_20m.zip"
tf    <- tempfile()
td    <- tempdir()
download.file(url,tf, mode="wb")  
unzip(tf, exdir=td)                

usa <- readOGR(dsn=td, layer="cb_2014_us_state_20m")
shp <- usa[(!usa$STUSPS %in% c("AK","HI")),] 

df<- fortify(shp)                    
df<- merge(df,cbind(id=rownames(shp@data),shp@data),by="id")   
df$state <- tolower(df$NAME)                                                  
df<- merge(df,mapdata,by="state")  
df<- df[order(df$order),]       

####function for tooltip
gg<-df
gg$id<-1:nrow(gg)
values<-function(x){
  if(is.null(x)) return(NULL)
  row<-gg[gg$id==x$id,]
  paste0("State: ",row$state,"<br />",
         "Revenue: ", row$revenue, "<br />")
}
####ggvis choropleth
gg %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  ggvis(~long, ~lat, key:=~id)  %>%
  hide_axis("x") %>% 
  hide_axis("y")%>%
  add_tooltip(values,"hover")%>%
  layer_paths(fill= ~revenue)
```

Comment: You have `values` in `add_tooltip` yet `values` is a function. I couldnt work out what `x` is meant to be in the function.

Comment: I think this question is basically the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31360263/disappearing-values-in-ggvis-when-using-tooltip-on-grouped-data However, this latter one doesn't have a (valid) solution yet either.

Comment: And user @dsh in his comment on the accepted answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24519980/add-data-to-ggvis-tooltip-thats-contained-in-the-input-dataset-but-not-directly seems to suggest a similar issue - but again no follow-up there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was looking around a bit and realized that since paths are made from information from multiple rows of a dataset, it doesn't make sense to try to use a unique row id for the tooltip like we usually do with `key`.

Then I saw this [very nice ggvis tutorial](http://rud.is/b/2014/12/29/making-static-interactive-maps-with-ggvis-using-ggvis-maps-wshiny/), and the way forward became clearer to me.  You need to base the tooltip on your *grouping* variable, and then somehow winnow the info from the many rows in that group down to a single value.  Among other options, you could do this by pulling out just the first row from the group or by using just the `unique` value when making your in your tooltip function.

Here's examples of what I mean, using the variable `group` that you use in  `group_by` to pull out the pertinent info.

First, using `head` to get just the first row:

```
values = function(x){
    if(is.null(x)) return(NULL)
    row = head(gg[gg$group == unique(x$group), ], 1)
    paste0("State: ", row$state,"<br />",
           "Revenue: ", row$revenue, "<br />")
}
```

Alternatively, just pull the `unique` values of the variables you want to display (there is one per state/group).  This works OK in your case because you are only displaying two values:

```
values2 = function(x){
    if(is.null(x)) return(NULL)
    row = gg[gg$group == unique(x$group), ]
    paste0("State: ", unique(row$state),"<br />",
           "Revenue: ", unique(row$revenue), "<br />")
}
```

Now take the `key` argument out of `ggvis` and use one of the new tooltip functions.  Now the interactive graph appears to work fine.

```
gg %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    ggvis(~long, ~lat)  %>%
    hide_axis("x") %>% 
    hide_axis("y")%>%
    add_tooltip(values, "hover")%>%
    layer_paths(fill= ~revenue)
```

Comment: Smith, I just post another question about tooltip function and shiny reactive http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33133163/how-to-put-ggvis-tooltip-function-into-shiny-reactive-in-r

Comment: Smith, thank you for replying my post. I have a question about..when do I need key:=id for tooltip? And why we don't put key:=group here?

Comment: @ouou When you want to show information associated with a single row, such as when showing the info associated with a single plotted point (I've done this a lot).  My understanding is that the `key` variable must always have unique values across the entire dataset you are using to plot (and `group` wouldn't, because you have multiple records per level).

Comment: Hi Smith. I post another question here. Can you have a look to see if you could help? Thanks a lot! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267604/switch-ggivs-plots-based-on-radio-buttons-in-r-shiny