# Possible bug for tooltip in ggivs?

Tags: r, ggvis

The code below doesn't work as it should, 
which is that when the pointer is hovering over a point,
it should show the Num...

```
iris$Sepal.Length.j <- jitter(iris$Sepal.Length)
iris$Sepal.Width.j <- jitter(iris$Sepal.Width)
iris$Num <- 1:nrow(iris)
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% 
  ggvis(~Sepal.Length.j, ~Sepal.Width.j, opacity:=0.5) %>% 
  layer_points(fill=~Species) %>% layer_smooths(stroke=~Species) %>%
  add_tooltip(html=function(x) {
    if (!is.list(x)) return()
    x$Num}, on="hover")
```

Is this a possible bug or am I misunderstood?
The code below works fine.

```
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% 
  ggvis(~Sepal.Length.j, ~Sepal.Width.j, opacity:=0.5) %>% 
  layer_points(fill=~Species) %>% layer_smooths(stroke=~Species) %>%
  add_tooltip(html=function(x) {
    if (!is.list(x)) return()
    x$Sepal.Width}, on="hover")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things going on here.  First is about the data columns that *ggvis* uses.

From the "Examples" section of the `add_tooltip` help page:

> The data sent from client to the server contains only the data columns
>   that are used in the plot. If you want to get other columns of data,
>   you should to use a key to line up the item from the plot with a row
>   in the data.

In your second plot, `Sepal.Width` was used in the plot and so was available for the tooltip.  But you never used `Num` in the plotting code so it wasn't available to be used in the tooltip.  To keep `Num` in the data columns for the plot, you need to indicate that this is your `key` column.

That's an easy fix - just add `key := ~Num` to `layer_points`.

There are some other subtle issues with grouping and tooltips, some of which are outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33129467/2461552).  In your case, if you group after `layer_points` and before `layer_smooth` I think the tooltip works as you would like it to.

So your code could look like:

```
iris %>%
    ggvis(~Sepal.Length.j, ~Sepal.Width.j, opacity:=0.5) %>% 
    layer_points(fill=~Species, key := ~Num) %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>%
    layer_smooths(stroke=~Species) %>%
    add_tooltip(html=function(x) {
        if (!is.list(x)) return()
        x$Num}, on="hover")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no column called "Num" in the input dataset to your plot - that's why it isn't working. Your second example works because "Sepal.Width" is a column in the iris data.

Comment: I don't know how you are getting those columns. Are you sure you have provided all the code you ran above?

Comment: This is what I ran: 

`library(ggvis)

data(iris)

iris$Sepal.Length.j <- jitter(iris$Sepal.Length)
iris$Sepal.Width.j <- jitter(iris$Sepal.Width)`

Comment: I get: colnames(iris)
[1] "Sepal.Length"   "Sepal.Width"    "Petal.Length"   "Petal.Width"    "Species"        "Sepal.Length.j" "Sepal.Width.j"

Comment: Looks like this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31360263/disappearing-values-in-ggvis-when-using-tooltip-on-grouped-data?rq=1